# Can we ad-hoc distribute MAC App?

Tags: macos, distribution, store

I am very new in Mac app development. I noticed there is not much information how MAC apps are developed and distributed. I have basic questions.

Can we distribute/sell the Mac app build for (Mac app-store) directly to the customers?

Or can we use Mac App development tools to make App which we can distribute without app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can distribute applications for MacOSX (non iOS) without app store.

Answer (score 1):

You can build and distribute your Mac application however you want.

*If* (and only if) you want to distribute through the App Store you need to pay Apple a cut for it, pay for a developer account, and follow the App Store rules, but you can still also distribute the application in any way you want beside that; the Mac App Store distribution deal isn't exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute Mac Apps without the Mac Store. However, if your app wants to use iCloud, you need to distribute it via the Mac App Store (or deliver an AdHoc distribution to hardware-registered Macs, limited to 100 developer machines per year). Only applications downloaded through the Mac App Store are allowed to access their iCloud container.

Also: you need to be a registered Mac App developer and sign your app if you wish that gatekeeper automatically opens your app (since Mountain Lion 10.8.). Otherwise users have to disable gatekeeper, change its settings or (first) launch the app via the context menu > open.